# On edit update pivot table - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table

I have tables `questions`, `tags` and a pivot table `question_tag`. `question_tag` table has only two fields `question_id` and `tag_id`.

When I add a question, it also inserts corresponding values to pivot table.

Suppose I change question tags in form and save, it should update the pivot table values. How can I update pivot table? I'm new to laravel.
I tried something like

```
$question->tags()->updateExistingPivot($tag_id, array('any attribute'=>$value));
```

but in my case there is no extra attributes in pivot table

Question Model

```
public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
```

Tag Model

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question');
}
```

Comment: So you're just wanting to be able to add or remove tags from a question? Do you have a form and controller method in place for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$question->tags()->updateExistingPivot($question->id, ['tag_id' => $newTag->id]);
```

The first value is what you want to match. If you want to match questions then it should be the question id. The second parameter are the columns to update so passing it an array with the new tag will work. I wrote a test and it worked fine.

```
/** @test */
public function it_can_update_the_pivot_table()
{
    // Create a Tag
    $tag      = factory(Tag::Class)->create();

    // Create a Question
    $question = factory(Question::Class)->create();

    // Create a pivot table record
    DB::table('question_tag')->insert(['question_id' => $question->id, 'tag_id' => $tag->id]);

    // Assert that there is a pivot table record before we attempt to change it
    $this->assertNotNull(DB::table('question_tag')->where([
        ['question_id', $question->id],
        ['tag_id', $tag->id],
    ]));

    // Attempt to change the with the tag id of the tag we created above.
    $question->tags()->updateExistingPivot($tag->id, ['tag_id' => 2]);

    // Query all pivot table records with the question id
    $new = DB::table('question_tag')->where(
        'question_id', $question->id
    )->first();

    // assert that the pivot record was updated
    $this->assertEquals(2, $new->tag_id);
}
```

Comment: i think it should be `$tag_id` instead `$question->id` in answer

Comment: @rkj It really depends. If he want's to grab all records in the `question_tag` table by question id then `$question->id` is what is needed. If he needs to query by tag id then `$tag_id` will work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$question->tags()->sync([$tag_id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$question->pivot->attribute = "Value";`

`$question->pivot->save();`